# Adding a composite foreign key to an existing sql table

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
create table x (a int primary);
create table y (b int primary);
create table z (c int, d int, e int);
```

I am (later on purpose) adding a composite foreign key to z:

```
alter table z add constraint c foreign key (c) references x(a)
alter table z add constraint d foreign key (d) references y(b)
```

Is it possible to add this composite foreign key to the existing table in a single sql instruction?

Comment: There is no composite foreign key in your example

Comment: This is not a composite constraint, these are two difderent constraints to two difderent tables. So no, It's not possible.

Comment: Will I be able to add a single composite constraint spanning over those two different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create this as a single composite constraint, because it references two different tables - but it could be possible (depending on your DBMS) to add the two constraints in a single sql instruction (although I don't think it's generally recommended). You can e.g. find examples for [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020167.html) or [SQLServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865662/sql-alter-add-multiple-fks).

So this could be possible:

```
ALTER TABLE z 
  ADD CONSTRAINT c FOREIGN KEY (c) REFERENCES x(a) 
  ADD CONSTRAINT d FOREIGN KEY (d) REFERENCES y(b)
```

Comment: That syntax depends on the DBMS Michael is using - which we don't know

Comment: According to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, you can only add one fk per alter table statement.

Comment: Thank you both - I edited the answer accordingly. 
a_horse_with_no_name: True, it was guess based on the syntax he provided - I might be wrong though. jarlh: Also likely true (I couldn't check), but you some DBs still seem to allow it, e.g. also SQL Server